# How to send DTMF tones in active call in android?

Tags: android, dtmf

Is it possible to send DTMF tones in active call in android ? I tried it with `proxyphone.sendDtmf()` but it was useless.

How can i achieve it ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In VOIP only it is possible,Android applications have no access to the in-call audio stream. You can fake a it a bit in speakerphone mode.

Comment: How can i do it in speakerphone mode ? Using Tonegenerator ?

Comment: I tried it with following code ToneGenerator mToneGenerator;
   mToneGenerator = new ToneGenerator(
     AudioManager.STREAM_VOICE_CALL, 100);
   

   
   if (mToneGenerator != null) {
    tone++;
    mToneGenerator.startTone(tone,500);
    if(tone==9)
    {
     tone=0;
    }
   }    but not getting tone at other hand

Comment: int durationMs = 500;
int volume_level = 100;

final ToneGenerator mToneGenerator = new ToneGenerator(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC, volume_level); // Raising volume to 100% (For eg. 7 * 14 ~ 100)
            mToneGenerator.stopTone();
            mToneGenerator.startTone(ToneGenerator.TONE_DTMF_0, durationMs); // playsound for 500ms

Answer (score -2):

Try this method() .It is getting the number and delay from user.

```
private void call(int profileid) {//call procedure logic 
        ProfileDo profile = adapter.getProfile(profileid);
        if (profile.getStepCount() == 0) {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Please edit the profile and add atleast one value to make a call", 10000).show();
            return;}
            String call = "tel:";
        for (StepDO step : profile.getSteps()) {
            String value = URLEncoder.encode(step.getValue());
            int delay = step.getDelay();
            String pausesStr = "";
            for (int i = 0; i < delay / 2; i++) {
                pausesStr += PhoneNumberUtils.PAUSE;
            }
            call += value + pausesStr;
        }
         startActivity(new Intent("android.intent.action.CALL", Uri.parse(call)));      
    }
```